# In Symfony (2.3) is there any difference between equals and colon in route annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

There are 2 syntaxes used in the documentation. Separate the values by ':' or '='. Is there any difference?

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/routing.html

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/articles/{_locale}/{year}/{title}.{_format}",
 *     defaults={"_format": "html"},
 *     requirements={
 *         "_locale": "en|fr",
 *         "_format": "html|rss",
 *         "year": "\d+"
 *     }
 * )
 */
```

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

```
 * @Route("/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no difference as to which syntax you end up using. The annotation reader accepts both as valid **key** => **value** syntax.

I did some debugging to see if there would be any difference if you pass both syntaxes.

A simple controller (with the annotations you provided):

```
class TestController extends Controller {

    /**
    * @Route(
    *     "/articles/{_locale}/{year}/{title}.{_format}",
    *     defaults={"_format": "html"},
    *     requirements={
    *         "_locale" = "en|fr",
    *         "_format": "html|rss",
    *         "year": "\d+"
    *     }
    * )
    */
    public function testRouteAction() {
        return new Response();
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm using "**=**" for *_locale* and "**:**" for *_format*.

Then I dumped all route collections that are passed to AnnotationLoader. You can find and do some dumps on your own, if you're interested. The namespace of the loader is **Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationClassLoader** and can be found in vendor **symfony/symfony**.

Most of the magic happens in method **addRoute()** which accepts few arguments, one of which is instance of *Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route*, holding your parsed route with all of its options. Dumping the variable **$requirements** we can see the formatted array with requirements:

```
array (size=3)
  '_locale' => string 'en|fr' (length=5)
  '_format' => string 'html|rss' (length=8)
  'year' => string '\d+' (length=3)
```

So, to wrap it up - no, I believe there is not much of a difference which syntax you will use.

*- Edit -*

Tip: If you try to do some debugging as well, do **not** forget to clear your cache (environment does not matter) otherwise you will not see the result.

Comment: Yes, this matches our experience.